# Where can I find icons / vector art of everyday objects?

Tags: vector, icon

I am designing an application that requires between 100 - 200 icons / vector art of everyday objects - grandma, banana, boat, etc.

The resource that I've found that is closest to my needs is [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/) but, preferably, I would like something with a bit more color.

Are there any similar resources for this purpose?

(Note: I know I will have to pay someone for a unified look and feel, but I would like to mock out the application with default icons initially.)

Comment: Search for them. [IconFinder.com](http://www.iconfinder.com/) is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd have more luck with trying to specify icon groups. "Everyday objects" might not be restricted enough. You could do a search for "Kitchen icons", for example, or "Food icons" in any stock site.

If you buy icons from different packs, it'd still be difficult to end up with a unified look, so unless you want to pay someone to design them for you, I'd recommend (and this might sound like a ton of work, but if you are used to working with vectors it's not that bad) you actually draw your icons. Not colorful, detailed ones, but shapes and outlines might do.

Answer (score 1):

I realize these are along the same lines as the noun project, but they may just come in handy :)

- http://iconmonstr.com/
- http://www.glyphlibrary.com/

Just found this option as well, a unique website for creating your own on the fly if you ever need something quick and don't have illustrator around.

- http://www.chittram.com

And not sure if this is legit but it claims to convert your bitmaps to vector art!

- http://vectormagic.com/home

Comment: Thanks! On a side note, this was hilarious: http://iconmonstr.com/?s=unhappy

Answer (score 0):

How about [vecteezy.com](http://vecteezy.com) or [vectorart.org](http://vectorart.org)?

Answer (score 0):

here is another option about icons and vector art.

-http://www.shutterstock.com

-http://vector.me

Comment: Hello user15576! Thanks for your contribution and welcome to GDSE. Could you please elaborate a bit on your answer? We'd like our answers here to have some value for future visitors, even if any links in them break. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Iconsfind.com](http://www.iconsfind.com) is good, easy to browse, find and download.

[Seanau.com](http://www.seanau.com) is professional commerical icons provider.